# Solve for x: $x^2+2bx-a^2+8ab-15b^2=0$

Tags: quadratics

$$x^2+2bx-a^2+8ab-15b^2=0$$

I am having a problem with solving these kinds of equations. I just get confused and I don't see what I need to do. Can somebody help, give some trick how to solve these equations easily?

Answer (score 1):

It's $$(x+b)^2=(4b-a)^2,$$ which gives
$$x=3b-a$$ or $$x=a-5b$$

Comment: Thanks! But how am I supposed to see this? There are many equations like this and I get stumped on a bunch of them. Any tricks?

Comment: $ \sqrt{(4b-a)^2}=|4b-a|$

Comment: @Fred I am aware. This is all clear. But I am asking about other examples that are similar. I can never see what I am supposed to do.

Comment: @RiktasMath, there is something called "completing the square".https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square.  Apply this to quadratics (when you see anything with power 2) and answers naturally follow

Comment: @RiktasMath Here it's just the following formula. $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

$$a^2-8ab+15b^2=a^2-ab(3+5)+15b^2=a(a-3b)-5b(a-3b)$$

Now replace $2b$ with $a-3b-(a-5b)$

See [middle term factor](http://www.ask-math.com/quadratic-factorization-using-splitting-of-middle-term.html)

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2+2bx-a^2+8ab-15b^2=0$$ then $$\Delta = 4b^2-4(-a^2+8ab-15b^2) =4(a^2-8ab+16b^2)= 4(a-4b)^2$$so

$$ x_{1,2} = {-2b\pm 2(a-4b)\over 2} = -b\pm (a-4b)$$